# Getting the average of sound in last minute

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, analogread, sound

I am reading sound input every 60 seconds and I would like to calculate the average of sound during that period using non-blocking code; what should I do to change the way that I calculate it in separated function as I need to do something else with other sensors.

```
int calculateSoundValue(){
    int average = analogRead(0);
    // loop to calculate the average simple formula sum div nbr of calculated times
    return average;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop() {
  // I donùt wanna calculate the average inside a loop but instead inside a function 
  int value = calculateSoundValue();
  Serial.println(value);

  delay(600);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Is this what you mean ?

```
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 6000;  
int totalSamples = 0; 
int count = 0

    int calculateSoundValue(){
        int sound = analogRead(0);
        totalSamples+= sound;
        count += 1;
        return totalSamples/count;
    }

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
int totalSamples = 0; 
int count = 0
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

  }
      int value = calculateSoundValue();
      Serial.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how average is calculated?

Comment: Do you know what sound is?

Comment: `sleep(600)` doesn't look like a minute, did you mean `delay()`? To do stuff with other sensors, you would have to have non-blocking code when you do the averaging on the reading.

Comment: @RSM Yes! that's the point behind my question; how can I make it non-blocking at the same time, I am doing a delay

Comment: @Avamander Harsh Answer!; Any way; in case you are familiar with arduino, you know that I meant how to make calculate the average on non-blocking way.

Comment: @user3378649 you didn't make it very clear that you wanted to make use of non-blocking code, so to a point it wasn't harsh, just practical and straight forward.

Comment: @user3378649 to make non-blocking code you can use the mill is() function, most suggest a look at the blink without delay example. Delay will block your code, I know timer interrupts still happen when a delay is running, so timer interrupts are what you can look into. Also 60*1000mS = 1 minute.

Comment: You don't need fancy software to tell you what the average sound over a minute will be... The answer is zero - or as near as makes no odds.

Comment: @RSM Please can you check the UPDATE, I tried to implement what you suggested; double check and enlighten us with your suggestions.

Comment: @Majenko I am trying to see whether there was a movement in the last minute or no; by using sound sensor

Comment: @RSM Then the average is not what you want - what you want to do is listen continuously and decide from moment to moment if there is sound above your trigger threshold or not and remember that fact - then once a minute look at what you have remembered and act on it.

Comment: @Majenko I don't audio stuff, but I agree with you on average being a waste of time, I was only thinking of the implementation methods. The OP might as well use a peak detector.

Comment: @RSM That may have been misdirected ;) It was supposed to be directed to the OP...

Comment: @Majenko its chilled :), any way it made me think further than the obvious, and the OP will have a pretty busy inbox now :)

Comment: @RSM It's the classic [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - the OP thinks they know what they want and how to achieve it, but can't work out how to implement that method - however the underlying method, and their basic understanding of it all, is completely wrong, so even if they manage to implement it as they think it should be it still isn't going to work. They're basically asking the wrong question.

Comment: @user3378649: Looks like you do not know what sound is... It's not the average of the signal you `analogRead()`, it's the _fluctuations_ of that signal above and below its average. The closest thing to “average of sound” you can get is the [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the [AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) part of the signal. You can compute that as low_pass(square(high_pass(signal))).

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the average of doing an `analogRead` over a minute, is that it?

How about this?

```
unsigned long total;
unsigned int count;

unsigned long whenStarted;

const unsigned long INTERVAL = 60000;  // one minute

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println (F("Starting ..."));
  whenStarted = millis ();
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
  // one more sample
  total += analogRead (0);
  count++;

  if (millis () - whenStarted >= INTERVAL) // is a minute up?
    {
    Serial.print (F("Average = "));
    Serial.println (total / count);
    total = 0;
    count = 0;
    whenStarted = millis ();
    }
}  // end of loop
```

Comment: Thanks! can I put  total += analogRead (0); count++; on q function and replace it like I did

Comment: ...but as already pointed out, averaging the readings won't accomplish anything useful

Comment: `Thanks! can I put total += analogRead (0); count++; on q function and replace it like I did` - I don't know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you actually want is to measure sound intensity. This is
significantly more involved than just averaging the samples you read. I
have written a few weeks ago a program that does exactly that: it
measures the sound intensity and sends those measurements through the
serial port. It is a pretty short program (43 lines of code) you may be
able to adapt to your needs, so I am now sharing it as a GitHub gist:
[sound-meter.ino](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/e693799f58a545ca89a2).

In order for this not to be a link-only answer, I'll try to explain the
program's inner working, and go through the theory of measuring sound
intensity on an Arduino. But first let me put here a disclaimer: a
“real” sound level meter should have a frequency response that complies
with some standards, and it should be calibrated to absolute levels.
This program only provides uncalibrated readings with whatever frequency
response its analog hardware has.

### Signal conditioning

Four measuring sound on an Arduino, you obviously need a microphone,
but you also need some kind of interface circuit between the microphone
and the Arduino. The purpose of the interface is to “condition the
signal”, i.e. to make sure the Arduino gets a voltage in the proper
range for it's analog-to-digital converter (ADC). It's typically an
op-amp based circuit that provides some amplification and also adds a DC
bias to avoid clipping the negative side of each oscillation. Ideally,
the DC bias should be around Vcc/2, i.e. 2.5 V on an Arduino Uno.

See this [SparkFun microphone
breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9964) for an example on how
such a circuit may be built (click on “Schematic”).

### ADC sampling

Once you have a properly conditioned analog signal, you have to sample
it fast enough to catch all its spectral content. The [Nyquist–Shannon
sampling
theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)
tells us the sampling rate should be at least twice the highest
frequency in the signal. For audio signals, sampling rates of the order
of 8 kS/s (kilosamples per second) are typical of low quality,
telephone-like applications, whereas high quality audio would run at
44.1 to 48 kS/s.

The ADC of the Arduino Uno, in its default configuration, takes
104 µs to convert one sample. If you just call `analogRead()` in a
tight loop, this gives a sampling rate of about 9.6 kS/s, which is
fine for this kind of application, unless we have to measure noise above
4.8 kHz. The problem with this approach is that `analogRead()` is a
*blocking* function. Calling it in a tight loop means the program will
spend most of its time just waiting for the ADC. If you do anything else
in the loop, not only will the sampling rate be lowered, it will also
become unsteady, which is generally not desirable.

In order to avoid blocking the CPU, we have to forgo `analogRead()`, and
instead get our hands dirty with low-level configuration of the ADC. The
ADC of the Arduino Uno offers a so-called “free running mode”, which is
well suited for this kind of application. In this mode, the ADC starts a
new conversion as soon as the previous one is done, ensuring a very
consistent sampling rate of 9.6 kS/s. It can also trigger an
interrupt after each conversion, in order for the interrupt service
routine to retrieve and process the sample. See the [datasheet of the
ATmega328P](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)
for details on configuring the ADC.

### Removal of the DC bias

Once we have the digitized samples, the first thing to do is to remove
the DC bias that was added by the interface circuit. If the bias is
stable and known (maybe determined by experiment), this only involves
subtracting a constant. If it is not known, it can be estimated by
running the samples through a digital low-pass filter with a cutoff
frequency below the range of interest. Subtracting the output of a
low-pass filter is essentially building a high-pass filter. As an
alternative, a numerical derivative (difference between consecutive
samples) can be used as a crude high-pass filter. This, however, will
bias the sensitivity of the detection towards the high end of the
spectrum. Depending on the noise you want to detect, and on the
background noise, this could be acceptable for your application.

In the program I am sharing, I assume the DC bias is known: it's the
`dc_offset` constant at the beginning of the program.

### Instantaneous intensity

With the DC bias removed, the signal we have is a digital image of the
sound picked by the microphone. It could be tempting to just average it
as is. This, however, would just give zero, as the positive fluctuations
of the signal would cancel the negative ones.

The are several options to solve this problem. We could do a peak
detection instead of an average, or we could take the absolute value
before averaging. The most popular option is probably to compute the
squares of the samples. Since the square of a real number is always
positive, this avoids the averaging-out problem. But the square has also
a deeper physical meaning: it is proportional to the [sound
intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity), i.e. the
energy carried by the sound wave.

### Low-pass filter

The intensity computed above is a very fast varying quantity. If the
signal is a simple tone of constant frequency and volume, the
instantaneous intensity fluctuates between zero and some maximum at
twice the tone frequency. In order to recover the “constant volume”
property of the sound, we need to perform some sort of averaging or, in
other words, we need a low-pass filter.

There are many ways to implement a digital low-pass filter. The most
intuitive may be to group the samples into batches, and then compute the
average of each batch. However, this is neither the best nor the most
efficient to implement. When I need a quick and simple low pass filter,
I generally use an [exponential moving
average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).
This is the discrete-time equivalent of an analog RC filter, and it can
be implemented very efficiently by remembering the previous output and
updating it as

```c++
output += input - output / N;
```

where, for efficiency reasons, N should be a power of two. The filter's
time constant is N/f<sub>s</sub>, where f<sub>s</sub> is the sampling
frequency. In the program I use N = 256, which makes the
division virtually free. This gives a time constant of 26.6 ms. You
can tune the time constant to your needs simply by changing N, but make
sure it is still a power of two.

### Decimation

If you only want to trigger an event when the sound intensity exceeds a
defined level, you may not need this. But if you have other processing
to do with those measurements, it is probably not useful to process more
than one intensity reading per time constant of the previous filter.
That's why the program has a decimation step. This is simply the ISR
periodically signaling the main program that an intensity reading is
available. Notice that, since the sample count is an 8-bit variable, it
automatically counts modulo 256. If you want to increase the decimation
factor, you should make `sample_count` wider and mask out the bits you
do not need.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is use millis() to keep track of time. You can also put all the time related stuff inside a class to have a nicely organized code. You can get more info about time management on the Arduino here. https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/ditch-the-delay

Comment: You probably mean `micros()`, not `millis()`: If you want to sample the ADC at rates relevant to audio signals, `millis()` will not provide fine enough resolution.